# How can I run a macro changing the value of the cell (no carriage returns)?

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros

I can run a macro whenever a value is changed in a cell. However, I have to press the carriage return button to change the value of the cell. Is there any way to run a macro whenever I press a single numeric value in a cell *even before pressing the carriage return* ?

Comment: This IS possible using an API. See this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11153995/is-there-any-event-that-fires-when-keys-are-pressed-when-editing-a-cell

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible.  The [Excel VBA Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn301178.aspx) does not include an Event for the behavior you describe.

Excel itself likely doesn't handle this behavior, as calculations are not triggered until the value is accepted.